# How can I call brew from an Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, homebrew

I'm trying to create a script to check if Homebrew is installed on any given mac and in case it is if it has a particular formula installed. I have the part that checks if brew is installed, but when I try to run brew list to see what packages are installed I get "Command not found" even though I can run the command in the Terminal fine. I'm using:

```
do shell script "brew list"
```

Is there any other way to run brew commands in Applescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to call the command directly, otherwise AppleScript might not find the correct path returning `command not found` — To do that you'll want to see where the `brew` command is located in `Terminal`:

```
$ which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

Based off of this you should be able to do:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/brew list"
```

If you have multiple arguments after a command use the `-c` option:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/brew -c list <package>"
```

> If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from
>    string.  If there are arguments after the  string,  they  are
>    assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

If you wanted a complete way to figure out the path you might be able to do something such as:

```
set brewPath to do shell script "/usr/bin/which brew | awk '{print $0}'" as string
set brewList to do shell script "" & brewPath & " list" as string
```

<sub>*note: I haven't tested this, so it might require some adjustment.</sub>